# A group contain a compact open subgroup

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, topological-groups

Here's a proof:

Let $ψ : G → \mathbb{C} ^{\times} $ be a group homomorphism. The following are
equivalent:

$(1)$ $ψ$ is continuous;

$(2)$ the kernel of $ψ$ is open.
If $ψ$ satisfies these conditions and $G$ is the union of its compact open subgroups, then the image of $ψ$ is contained in the unit circle $|z| = 1$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Proof. Certainly (2) ⇒ (1). Conversely, let $N$ be an open neighbourhood of $1$
in $\mathbb{C}$. Thus $ψ^{−1}(N )$ is open and contains a compact open subgroup $K$ of $G$.
However, if $N$ is chosen sufficiently small, it contains no non-trivial subgroup
of $\mathbb{C} ^{\times} $  and so $K ⊂ Ker ψ$.

The unit circle $ S_1$ is the unique maximal compact subgroup of $\mathbb{C} ^{\times} $. If $K$
is a compact subgroup of $G$, then $ψ(K)$ is compact, and so it is contained in
$S_1$. The final assertion follows.

I want to know why  $K ⊂ Ker ψ$ then we can get (1)⇒ (2)?

Maybe a group contain a compact open subgroup will be a open group?

The proof is from the book《the local langlands conjecture for $GL(2)$ 》- colin j. bushnell, guy henniart,

Thank you for sharing your idea!

Comment: If $K\subset\ker\psi$ then $\ker\psi$ is a union of translates $gK$ of $K$, and hence is open.

Comment: Oh,I know,thanks